# Can't push the data to array using method of CSV file to Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to read csv file and categorized each marks and count them in a array.but halfway there,i can't push data which are got from csv to a array.

```
student | mark(out of 10)
1       |2
2       |4
3       |3
4       |3
```

(only need the second column values)

marksArray should be like this (count of marks)
`[0,1,0,1,2]`

```
const fs = require("fs");

function test(){
    var temp=[];
    fs.readFile("marks.csv", "utf8", function(err, data) {
  dataArray = data.split(/\r?\n/);

  for (i = 1; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
    var s = dataArray[i];
    var s1 = s.split(",");
    console.log(s1[1]);
    temp.push(s1[1]);


  }
});
return temp;

}

var i, j;

var marksArray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

data2=test();
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    if (data2[i] == j) {
      marksArray[j - 1]++;
    }
  }
}

console.log(data2);
console.log(marksArray);
```

Comment: Your `test()` function contain some asynchronous code (reading the file). You might want to use `fs.readFileSync` or turn your `test` function into a Promise and return `temp` only when you are done reading the file.

Comment: if this is a throwaway script, just move your handler logic (that nested for loop, and console logs) INTO the callback -https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback